# How to do Android datepicker To date greater than from date validation

Tags: android, date, datepicker, calendar

> I have two DatePicker. One with From date and other with To date. I want to 
>     display To date always greater than from date according to From date selection .I am using the Android default date picker, and want to disable the past 
>     dates of TO datepicker if its greater than the From date and vice versa. I know 
>     this topic has been asked many times here. But, I couldn't make my code work 
>     like the suggested solutions, so please help?

```
Calendar calendarOne = Calendar.getInstance();


     datePickerFrom= new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new  
     DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { 

     @Override 
     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, 
     int dayOfMonth) {
        StringBuilder selectedDate = new 
    StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append("-").append(monthOfYear + 
    1).append("-").append(year);
     fromText.setText(selectedDate);
     fromText.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
    } 

  }, calendarOne.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarOne.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
     calendarOne.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

 fromText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View view) {
        datePickerFrom.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new 
     Date().getTime()); 
        datePickerFrom.show(); 
    } 
}); 


  Calendar calendarTwo = Calendar.getInstance();
  datePickerTo = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new 
  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int 
    dayOfMonth) {
        StringBuilder selectedDate = new 
   StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append("-").append(monthOfYear + 
   1).append("-").append(year);
        toText.setText(selectedDate);
        toText.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
      } 
   }, calendarTwo.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarTwo.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
   calendarTwo.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

   toText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View view) {
       datePickerTo.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime()); 
       datePickerTo.show(); 
      } 
    }); 
   }
```

................................
Updated Code

```
    final Calendar calendarOne = Calendar.getInstance();
    datePickerFrom= new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
            {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, final int 
    monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {
                    StringBuilder selectedDate = new
                            StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append("-
      ").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-").append(year);
                  fromText.setText(selectedDate);
                  fromText.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);

                    Calendar calendarTwo = Calendar.getInstance();
                   datePickerTo = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity());


    datePickerTo.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendarOne.getTimeInMillis());

                   datePickerTo = new DatePickerDialog(activity, new 
   DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int 
    month, int dayOfMonth) {
                            StringBuilder selectedDate = new 
    StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append("-").append(monthOfYear + 
    1).append("-").append(year);
                              toText.setText(selectedDate);

   toText.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
                        }
                    }, calendarTwo.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
   calendarTwo.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendarTwo.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                      toText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                           datePickerTo.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new 
     Date().getTime());
                           datePickerTo.show();
                        }
                    });

                }

            }, calendarOne.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
      calendarOne.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendarOne.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

   fromText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datePickerFrom.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new
                    Date().getTime());
            datePickerFrom.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all declare following in your class before onCreate :**

```
private String fromDate;
private DatePickerDialog fromDatePicker;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener fromDatePickerListener;
private Calendar fromDateCalendar;
private String toDate;
private DatePickerDialog toDatePicker;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener toDatePickerListener;
private Calendar toDateCalendar;
```

**After that in your onCreate method add following code:**

```
fromDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDatePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fromDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            fromDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            fromDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            fromDate = fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            //etFromDate.setText(fromDate);
            toDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(fromDateCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        }

    };

    toDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    toDatePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            toDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            toDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            toDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            toDate = toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            //etToDate.setText(toDate);
        }

    };

    toDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),toDatePickerListener, toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    fromDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),fromDatePickerListener, fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

**Next step is when you want to show your datePicker upon clicking button or edit text where ever you want to show your date picker use following lines to show:**

```
fromDatePicker.show();
toDatePicker.show();
```

**Also you can use strings fromDate and toDate to show selected dates if you want to show them anywhere like in a textView or editText.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159407/discussion-on-answer-by-m-saad-lakhan-how-to-do-android-datepicker-to-date-great).

Comment: hai can anyone help